# PDO main variable naming. Is it a connection, or a handler, or a handle?

Tags: php

In the code below there is a variable named "dbh". Would you describe that variable as a "connection", a "handler", a "handle" or something else? This might seem as a trivial and non important question, but I would like to know what the most correct term to call that variable so I know what to call it when I talk about it.

```
try {
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=".DB_SERVER.";dbname=".DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: It's the Handler object.

Comment: its in the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php)

Comment: @Ghost It actually isn't...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a ["handle"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handle_%28computing%29) to the DB class.  In this case, it's actually referencing a PDO class instance, and I think that's what you should call it.

Comment: Thanks! I will call it handle!